# Wtforms, add a class to a form dynamically

Tags: python, css, flask, wtforms

is there a way i could send a form's (css) class from python?
For example:

```
class Company(Form):
    companyName = TextField('Company Name', [validators.Length(min=3, max = 60)])
```

This renders a simple text field, but i want that text field to have the css class of `.companyName`, is that possible directly from python?

I know that i can put a `id="companyName"` directly from python, but not class.

Help.

Update: 
I tried `class_="companyName"` and it did not work, i got:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_class'
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

WTForms does not allow you to set display options (such as class name) in the field initialization.  However, there are several ways to get around this:

1. If all of your fields should include a class name as well as an ID then just pass in each field's [`short_name`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.short_name) to it when you render it:

   ```
   <dl>
   {% for field in form %}
   <dt>{{field.label}}</dt>
   <dd>{{field(class_=field.short_name)}}</dd>
   {% endfor %}
   </dl>
   ```
2. Create a [custom widget](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/widgets.html#custom-widgets) mixin that provides the class name:

   ```
   from wtforms.fields import StringField
   from wtforms.widgets import TextInput

   class ClassedWidgetMixin(object):
       """Adds the field's name as a class 
       when subclassed with any WTForms Field type.

       Has not been tested - may not work."""
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(ClassedWidgetMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
           c = kwargs.pop('class', '') or kwargs.pop('class_', '')
           kwargs['class'] = u'%s %s' % (field.short_name, c)
           return super(ClassedWidgetMixin, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)

   # An example
   class ClassedTextInput(ClassedWidgetMixin, TextInput):
       pass

   class Company(Form):
       company_name = StringField('Company Name', widget=ClassedTextInput)
   ```

Answer (score 56):

Alternatively you can add the class in your template like this for jinja2:

```
{{ form.name(size=20, class_='input-small') }}
```

Comment: Saved me as well :) This is a wonderful solution, not sure why an example along these lines isn't somewhere in the WTForm docs

Comment: I'd vote up ten times if it is possible, this is a much better solution. Now I can sit back and watch WTForms rock~~~

Comment: Although the underscore after class doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: This solution is much better than the one chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

Use `render_kw` if using [WTForms >= 2.1](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#version-2-1) :

```
submit = SubmitField(u'Block Submit Buttom', render_kw={"class": "btn btn-primary btn-block"})
```

Comment: It works for me many days age, but it just failed now. I don't remember what I did then, but almost just like your answer. After Ctrl+F5, the submit button also shows it class **btn btn-default**:-(... Any possible errors?
 `WTForms==2.1` and `Flask-WTF==0.14.2`

Comment: It's perfectly what I need when I use parsley js for email validate.

Comment: It look great, it should work but I have the same problem: WTForms is inserting ```btn-default``` class; don't work for some reason. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In your template, try it

```
{{ form.companyName( **{'class': 'companyName'} ) }}
```

Comment: In Python functions you can't use "class" as a named argument because it's a language keyword. For example, `myfunc(class='xyz')` results in a SyntaxError. Using the `myfunc(**{'class': 'xyz'})` like shown above gets around that problem. Thanks for your example!