# Trying to add input-lg to wtform

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make my input field bigger on my wtform field. I found this post that shows how to use form-control,

> {{ form.email(class_="form-control") }} 
>   [Add a css class to a field in wtform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084886/add-a-css-class-to-a-field-in-wtform)

And this bootstrap one on how to use input-lg,

> input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp

But they are not working together in my code. There is no error it just doesn't work.

```
<form id="signinform" class="form form-horizontal" method="post"
          role="form" style="font-size:24px;”>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.last_name, class_="form-control input-lg") }}
</form>
```

There is a few more form lines but they don't need to be included.

How can I make this work? What am I doing wrong?
(I have bootstrap and everything already imported)

Thanks

Comment: if you have only one field then you can easily increase the field width, otherwise if you have more field , use a div and inside div use class "col-md-5" and "col-md-5 col-md-offset-2". see the bootstarp modal tutorial

Comment: I was able to actually just use some javascript and just it to be bigger, If you are having the same problem here is the code I used:  $(document).ready(function (){   $("#XX input").addClass('input-lg'); });             XX= id of the form

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS for the field. Name the field and then add the corresponding style to CSS.