# Disable fields if checkbox not ticked

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

In FlaskAdmin, how do I disable a set of fields so that they cannot be edited if a checkbox is not ticked? For instance, here if enabled is not checked, I would like to gray out the other fields so that they cannot be edited.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a cursory glance at the FlaskAdmin docs and similar questions on this site, there doesn't seem to be a clear way of accomplishing this. (I could be wrong as I haven't used this extension.) Despite that, you can accomplish this in JavaScript. In your Jinja, you can [pretty easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841273/5854907) set a class on your fields that can then be used to select elements in JavaScript. Here's a very rough example.

**Jinja**

```
{{ field(class_="checkbox") }}
{{ field(class_="input") }}
{{ field(class_="input") }}
{{ field(class_="input") }}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('body').off('change.checkbox')
    .on('.checkbox', 'change.checkbox', function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            return $('.input').attr('disabled', '');
        }
        return $('.input').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks for this Allie Fitter. After much research I have come to a similar conclusion. I had hoped not to have to do a bunch of extra templates though.

Comment: They should be relatively small files. I doubt it would bloat your codebase too much.