# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'render_field' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

So I just started using `Wtforms` in conjunction with `Flask`, I set up basic class and defined all of my fields in `forms.py` as you can see here...

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField, validators, PasswordField, DateField

class AddAccount(Form):
    username = TextField('Username', [validators.Length('min=3, max=20')])
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Length('min=1, max=255')])
    karma = TextField('Karma', [validators.Length('min=1, max=10000000')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.Length('min=6, max=255')])
```

then I imported the `AddAccount` class into `views.py` as you can see here...

```
from forms import AddAccount

@app.route('/dashboard/add', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_account():

    form = AddAccount(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        print('POST request')


    return render_template('add_account.html', form=form)
```

and here's the template file...

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <br>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
       <h1>Add an Account</h1>
       <hr>
       <form action="{{url_for('add_account')}}">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{render_field(form.username, class_='form-control')}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{render_field(form.email, class_='form-control')}}    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{render_field(form.password, class_='form-control')}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{render_field(form.karma, class_='form-control')}}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

That whole contraption cause this error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'render_field' is undefined` and I have absolutely no idea why it's happening or how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

And if it helps... here's the stack trace...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "E:\Python\manager\views.py", line 37, in add_account
    return render_template('add_account.html', form=form)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "E:\Python\manager\templates\add_account.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  File "E:\Python\manager\templates\layout.html", line 22, in top-level template code
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  File "E:\Python\manager\templates\add_account.html", line 10, in block "body"
    {{render_field(form.username, class_='form-control')}}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'render_field' is undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you think there's a `render_field` Function? Any reference on this, what docs are you reading? Anyways, this should do the trick:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <br>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
       <h1>Add an Account</h1>
       <hr>
       <form action="{{url_for('add_account')}}">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.username(class_='form-control')}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.email(class_='form-control')}}    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.password(class_='form-control')}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.karma(class_='form-control')}}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also see [Add a css class to a field in wtform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084886/add-a-css-class-to-a-field-in-wtform).

Comment: thank you I was stuck on this. What is the benefit of using a macro render_field?

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to create partial file eg _formhelpers.html.
2. go to [this link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/) and copy the Forms in Templates code and past it in the _formhelpers.html that you have created
3. in your template file add this line of code

```
{% from '_formhelpers.html' import render_field %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably create a new file as `_formhelpers.html` with content as

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Then, include the same just before the form is loaded in VIEW

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Register </h1>
{% from '/includes/_formhelpers.html' import render_field %}
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.name ,class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

This should solve the problem for you. Thanks!

Documentation can be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates)

Answer (score -2):

You must use this code:

```
{% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
```

for template file.

Or you can include _fromhelpers.html.