# Add class to double curly brackets

Tags: html, css

i am using the double curly brackets to import variables into my html from my python code. I was inquiring on how to add class to these curly brackets in order to modify the variable in css. Here is a piece of code I am working on.

```
              <div>  
                {{ form.username.label(class ='username-label') }}
                <div>
                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {{ form.username }}
                        <div>
                            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.username }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

I tried to add class into the form.username.label in order to change the appearance of the label but it doesnt work. Is there a way to do it. I want it specifically for that label and not the whole div. I hope the only solution is not to add another div tag to the variable

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? If you want to format e.g. the `span` with the error in, just add a class *as part of the HTML*, not the templating - `<span class="error-message">{{ error }}</span>`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, whether I get you correctly.

```
{{ form.username.label(class_='username-label') }}
```

should become

```
{{ form.username.label(class_='username-label with-errors') }}
```

in case the form is invalid.

I'd approach it with

```
<div>
    {% if form.username.errors %}
        {{ form.username.label(class ='username-label with-errors') }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form.username.label(class ='username-label') }}
    {% endif %}
    <div>
        {% if form.username.errors %}
            {{ form.username }}
            <div>
                {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.username }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you could use actual `<label>` and an `<ul>` for improving semantics.

Edit: Added underscores, so `class_` is applied in a Flask template correctly.

Comment: my question was if one is able to style that class in css. For instance, that class 'username-label'...i want to style it in css ..is it usually possible?

Comment: Depends on what gets rendered (can't tell without knowing the template language - jitsi2?).
If you want to target a HTML class in CSS, the selector has a `.` (dot). E.g. `.username-label { background-color: red; }`

Comment: so it is actually possible to style it in css as you could stlye any other tag right? coz when i try to style it the label does not change according to the styling i have applied...that is my query. I know how to style in css, i just one to know if it is possible to style that variable inside the double curly brackets which in this case is 'username-label'...i hope you have understood me now..thanks

Comment: What is rendered in the client / web browser? Right now I see a mix of template language with HTML. A „tag” is the part between the angle brackets. Your example is rather a text node and not a tag. `{{` and `}}` are delimiters for interpolation, i.e. parts of the template that will get replaced with content.

Comment: yes exactly...now i want to style that part of the template that will get replaced(the delimiters),  by assigning it a class and then use that class in css

Comment: Can you interpolate within `class="({{ interpolation }})`? My understanding was, that `form.username.label` would generate a `<label>` with the attribute `class` set to `username-label`. That's why I asked, what gets rendered in the browser?
(e.g. by looking at the Inspector tab in the DevTools of your web browser).

Comment: yes it does generate a <label> but the class attribute has not been set...i have set up the class 'username-label' in my css but it is not getting rendered in the browser

Comment: Okay, so what technology do you use with the above markup? Django/Flask? PHP?
Do you happen to know the name of the template language being used?
Perhaps you're missing something …

Comment: i use flask (and python)...i also suspect i am missing something

Comment: i am not sure about the templating language. i am a begginer

Comment: Hey, welcome to the Python community then!
Personally, I haven't worked with Flask myself yet, but according to its website, it's using Jinja (like Django - what I worked with already).
So if I take a look at their documentation, this should work: `{{ form.username.label(class_='username-label') }}` (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841273/5189920 ) -- Note the underscore after `class` since it is a reserved keyword in Python!

Comment: nice nice....it has worked..thanks a lot men..not all  heroes wear caps..i guess django is like a 'larger' version of flask

Comment: i will sensei...namaste