# Set WTForms submit button to icon

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, iconic

I want a submit button that displays an icon rather than text.  The button is a field in a WTForms form.  I am using Bootstrap and Open Iconic for styling and icons.  How do I set the submit field to display an icon?

```
class MyForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField('')
```

```
{{ form.submit }}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668029/creating-a-form-with-a-varying-number-of-repeated-subform-in-flask-wtforms) refers to an `icon` method, but I can't find any more information on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example you linked is using macros provided by Flask-Bootstrap.  The macros make it easy to construct forms with Bootstrap, but might not be flexible.  For example, they probably don't support using Open Iconic icons instead.

Typically, you don't need to specify the submit button in the form, as it doesn't contribute useful data.  Render the submit as a button in the template manually and set whatever content you need.

```html
<button type=submit class="btn btn-primary"><span class="oi oi-check" title="Submit"></span></button>
```

If you do need a `SubmitField` in your form, you can set the label to a `Markup` string with the HTML.  The `Markup` is needed to tell Jinja it's safe to render without escaping.

```
from markupsafe import Markup
submit_value = Markup('<span class="oi oi-check" title="Submit"></span>')
submit = SubmitField(submit_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to render a submit field *with* an image icon instead of submit label text, in your html template, you can do something like this:

(assuming your form field name is isubmit):

```
<button type="submit" style="border: 0 none; background: none;" name="isubmit" value="x"><img src="/static/previousButton.png"></button>
```

note: value has to be non-empty, but it doesn't matter what it is; only img will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so, you can do this to use wtforms, and simply call `{{ render_temple(form) }}` in html to get this result.

```
class InlineButtonWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, class_=None):
        self.class_ = class_

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('type', 'submit')
        kwargs["class"] = self.class_
        title = kwargs.pop('title', field.description or '')
        params = html_params(title=title, **kwargs)

        html = '<button %s>%s</button>'
        return HTMLString(html % (params, escape(field.label.text)))


class InlineButton(Field):
    widget = InlineButtonWidget()

    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None, text='Save', **kwargs):
        super(InlineButton, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)
        self.text = text

    def _value(self):
        if self.data:
            return u''.join(self.data)
        else:
            return u''
```

Usage:

```
class BookForm(FlaskForm):
    text = Markup('<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Submit')
    submit = SubmitField(text, widget=InlineButtonWidget(class_="btn btn-info")) #This class_ param it's applied in the class of the button in HTML.
```

Output:

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tks5r.png)

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnLnJ.png)

My reply is based on this post [WTForms creating a custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510630/wtforms-creating-a-custom-widget).