# Use icon in wtforms SubmitField?

Tags: html, flask, wtforms

I know this looks like a duplicate of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147578/set-wtforms-submit-button-to-icon), in which the answer gives two solutions. But these solutions don't work for me. I am trying to rewrite this html to be rendered with wtforms. I have an < i > tag with a font-awesome icon inside a button tag:

```
        <button id="symbolBtn" class="mybtn btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit"
            name="submit-button" value="search">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
```

[image: this looks good!]

The first solution to the similar question suggests using Markup to define the html to be used as a value - for this solution I am trying this:

```
from markupsafe import Markup

BuyForm(FlaskForm):
    # The fields in question:
    search = StringField("Search", id="symbolInput", validators=[validSymbol])
    search_icon = Markup("<i class="fas fa-search"></i>")
    search_button = SubmitField(search_icon, id="symbolBtn")

    # Other fields in the same form
    shares = IntegerField("Shares", id="amountInput", validators=[validBuyAmount])
    shares_button = SubmitField("Refresh", id="amountBtn")
    submit_button = SubmitField("Buy")
```

I have multiple SubmitFields (submit buttons) and validate differently depending what SubmitField was pressed. But the icon isn't rendered - the html string is being rendered as text in the button. I can see that the quotation marks are a problem and I've tried differnet combinations:

```
Markup('<i class="fas fa-search"></i>')
Markup("<i class='fas fa-search'></i>")
Markup("<i class=\"fas fa-search\"></i>")
```

etc... But each attempt just renders text. Like where the html source on inspect is, for example:

```
value="<i class='fas fa-search'></i>"
```

[image: this is bad :-(]

Which I guess is logical, so how is it that people get this to work?

The second solution in the similar question suggests writing it out as plain html, but I need to check which button was pressed from the custom wtforms validators, for example validSymbol(form, field) for which I need to be able to say:

```
if form.search_button.data:
    # Search button was pressed. Check if search field contains valid data.
```

Is what I want to do not possible or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you ever figured it out and Markup was not working for me either but here is what i did.

In my forms i made a class and submitfield

```
class FavoriteForm(FlaskForm):
    favorite = SubmitField('Favorite')
```

In my routes i did

```
if fav.validate_on_submit:
    if fav.data['favorite']: # If favorite comes back True
        #code
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

and in my html i did

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ fav.hidden_tag() }}
    <button type="submit" name="favorite" value="x" class="follow-btn"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"> Favorite</i></button>
</form>
```

Your button has to have a name and a value.
name has to be the name you used for your SubmitField in your forms and value can be what ever you want it to just not empty.

Comment: This is a better solution than what I ended up doing, I think. I ended up just making the submit button and doing stuff with it in the view function without directly connecting it with the wtf form.